# How to convert/sort a String based on two symbols in Java?

Tags: java, string, sorting, java-8

I have the following string:

```
String string = "bbb,aaa,ccc\n222,111,333\nyyy,xxx,zzz";
```

And I'm trying to convert it to:

```
String converted = "aaa,bbb,ccc\n111,222,333\nxxx,yyy,zzz";
```

To be somehow sorted. This is what I have tried so far:

```
String[] parts = string.split("\\n");
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
for(String part : parts) {
    list.add(part.split(","));
}

for(int i = 0, j = i + 1, k = j + 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String[] part = list.get(i);
    System.out.println(part[i]);
}
```

So I managed to get first element from each "unit" separately. But how to get all and order them so I get that result?

Can this be even simpler using Java8?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the purpose of these `j` and `k` variables in your second loop?

Comment: @Holger, Innocent copy-paste leftovers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess one way to do it would be:

```
String result = Arrays.stream(string.split("\\n"))
                          .map(s -> {
                              String[] tokens = s.split(",");
                              Arrays.sort(tokens);
                              return String.join(",", tokens);
                          })
                          .collect(Collectors.joining("\\n"));

System.out.println(result); // aaa,bbb,ccc\n111,222,333\nxxx,yyy,zzz
```

Just notice that in case your patterns are more complicated than `\n` or `,` - it is a good idea to extract those an separate `Pattern`(s)

Comment: This is the correct answer because of `Collectors.joining("\\n")`. I don't understand the down-vote :( Have my +1.

Comment: @Nikolas as a side note: you don't need to care about downvotes without a comment, I stopped to care about those ones a long time ago

Comment: Thanks Eugen, also voted-up now. Don't know why I got so many downvotes by I know that your answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String string = "bbb,aaa,ccc\n222,111,333\nyyy,xxx,zzz";
    String converted = Arrays.stream(string.split("\\n"))
            .map(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(","))
                    .sorted()
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(",")))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\\n"));
```

Comment: Neutralized. But a general suggestion, it makes more sense to explain what and why a block of code have you shared as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it *the old fashioned way* **without the use of Java 8** like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "bbb,aaa,ccc\n222,111,333\nyyy,xxx,zzz";
    System.out.println(sortPerLine(s));
}

public static String sortPerLine(String lineSeparatedString) {
    // first thing is to split the String by the line separator
    String[] lines = lineSeparatedString.split("\n");

    // create a StringBuilder that builds up the sorted String
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // then for every resulting part
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        // split the part by comma and store it in a List<String>
        String[] l = lines[i].split(",");
        // sort the array
        Arrays.sort(l);
        // add the sorted values to the result String
        for (int j = 0; j < l.length; j++) {
            // append the value to the StringBuilder
            sb.append(l[j]);
            // append commas after every part but the last one
            if (j < l.length - 1) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
        }
        // append the line separator for every part but the last
        if (i < lines.length - 1) {
            sb.append("\n");
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

But still, Java 8 should be preferred in my opinion, so stick to one of the other answers.

Comment: @Holger I have adjusted the answer to be pure < Java 8using your suggestions among other things, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `Pattern` class gives you a possibility to stream directly splitted `String`s.

```
String string = "bbb,aaa,ccc\n222,111,333\nyyy,xxx,zzz";
Pattern commaPattern = Pattern.compile(",");
String sorted = Pattern.compile("\n").splitAsStream(string)
    .map(elem -> commaPattern.splitAsStream(elem).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining(",")))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Comment: But when you perform `Pattern.compile` inside a function applied to every element, you’re destroying the benefit of preparing a `Pattern` and could have used the equivalent method on `String` which may call `Pattern.compile` under the hood. In this specific example, `String.split` will be even more efficient as it handles single-character patterns without special meaning on its own without the whole regex machinery (and the input strings are rather short).

Comment: @Holger You're right in terms of preparing the `Pattern`. One could create a constant. But - without knowing the actual implementation - I would assume that splitting and then streaming less memory efficient.

Comment: Letting `String`’s undocumented optimization aside, it’s best to assume that there will be a number of elements at which the array created before streaming needs more memory than the alternative. So for production code with unknown input or when you chain short-circuiting operations, `Pattern.splitAsStream` is indeed the better choice.